# Сommon font for formulas and text

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I use PSCyr to use TimesNewRoman. This command `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}` does it succesfully for text and 
doesn't make corrections to math-mode. How can I use TimesNewRoman for formulas without XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to leave `PSCyr` alone and use a more modern setup.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{tempora}   % Times like with Cyrillic support
\usepackage{newtxmath} % Times like for math

\begin{document}

Эрдэни Цырендоржиев

$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want `ftm`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

Эрдэни Цырендоржиев

$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately now the text does not match the font,  in Э straight line, not wavy

Comment: I added how to use `ftm`

Comment: 1 more: check ```$\textit{\text{p}}$``` and $p$, they are different. It means commands changed font for numbers, and what can you say about MathTimePro?

Comment: @ЭрдэниЦырендоржиев Of course they are.

Comment: How can i fix it? It'll be better if i would use TimesNewRoman for english alphabet too.